# Creating R package - dependencies

Tags: r, github, devtools

I wrote a little test package for R, located here: https://github.com/sho-87/Romdb/

I've been trying to use devtools `install_github()` to install the package but it complains that I dont have the stringi and curl packages installed:

> Using github PAT from envvar GITHUB_PAT
>      Downloading GitHub repo sho-87/Romdb@master
>      Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘curl’

I have those packages listed in the description file: https://github.com/sho-87/Romdb/blob/master/DESCRIPTION

Is there a reason why R isn't automatically installing those packages to my system when I try to install the package from github?

When I manually install those dependencies (`install.packages("curl")`) I can install from Github no problem...

Comment: I'm pretty sure they'll install if you put them under Depends.

Comment: I tried that earlier. It didn't seem to work

Comment: Need more clues. What was the output?

Comment: Just added error output to the original questiom

Comment: if you're using `install_github` from **devtools**, you should already have **curl**. It's on the Imports list. Maybe you installed **devtools** from source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have import statements in your Roxygen headers and `NAMESPACE` file. First, add `@import` statements to your Roxygen headers (for example, `@import httr`). If you are using RStudio, you can `Ctrl-Shift-D` to automatically update the `NAMESPACE` file.

See http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html